# Even Tensorflow < 1.6 shows "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have an laptop running Ubuntu 19.10. It is not the very best, so the processor isn't the best either and it doesn't have avx.

I trained a computer vision model in Google Colab and now I want to work with the model on my pc, because I want to use my webcam and I really don't want to activate my webcam in Colab.

What can I do to install Tensorflow on my computer?

### Edit

Even versions < 1.6 do not work it still throws `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Or you can try older version of tensorflow 1 or 1.15 and use CPU only pip package